# SQLData Oracle Type accessing via not the owner

Tags: java, database, oracle, mapping

I have a little issue, my Java code currently works fine when using the owner of the Oracle Types using the SQLData interface. but when I change the database user to not the owner I am getting a class cast exception as the returned type is a STRUCT not the Java class.

I have granted execute on the types and created public synonyms, but I am still having the issues.

Any ideas?

Cheers,
Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by adding the schema owner to the Sql Type name.

```
public class MyOracleType implements SQLData{ 
    public static final String SQL_TYPE = "MYSCHEMA.MY_ORACLE_T";

    public String getSQLTypeName() {
        return SQL_TYPE;
    }
```